# Mocking with java 1.4

Tags: java, mocking

Is there any framework, whick allows to mock concrete classes, not only interfaces in java 1.4? I have third party code with a singleton class, where I wanna change one function, without touching orignal code. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JMock 1.2 supports this. Details [here](http://www.jmock.org/jmock1-cglib.html).

Comment: Can I use JMock without unit tests? As I see I need to extend class MockObjectTestCase? In my situation it would be very unhandy to use unit tests...

Comment: You don't need to use a unit test, but certain methods will need to be run. I haven't tried it, but you can check the source code of MockObjectTestCase and see if it does anything special that has to be called separately.

Comment: Is it possible to mock some class so _all_ instantiation of some class created after some moment are mocked? I know it is possible in jmockit, but it's only available for newer java.

Comment: @Filip, I don't think JMock naitively supports such a concept. Of course you could fake it by having a factory produce the object with that logic in it. AFAIK such a feature requires classloader intervention, which would make it tricky to run in a production system.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend Mockito. A port to Java 1.4 is [available here](http://code.google.com/p/mockito/wiki/MockitoForJvm14).

Comment: I'm trying to use Mockito with Java 1.4 and ran into a problem almost immediately:  
`MyClass myClass = (MyClass) mock(MyClass.class);  
when(myClass.returnsInt()).thenReturn(???);`  

thenReturn returns only an Object. Not a problem with auto boxing/unboxing in Java 1.5, but I don't know how to get around this problem in Java 1.4.

Comment: Scratch that. If I write `when(myClass.returnsInt()).thenReturn(new Integer(1));` it looks like Mockito converts the Integer to a primitive int on a call to `returnsInt()` and everything "just works".